# Add text to h2 elements using forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that adds text to all my h2 elements using a for each loop. However, it seems to add the text to all h2 elements every time it loops. How can I fix it so it adds the text to each h2 only once? New to programming so sorry if this is a noob question. Thanks in advance. :)

```
RentalProperty.prototype.available = function(obj) { 
    let h2s = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
    h2s.forEach(h2 => {
        if(obj.availability == false) {
            h2.textContent += " - no vacancies";
        }
        else {
            h2.textContent += " - has vacancies";
        }       
    });
}
```

Output:

Rental 1 - no vacancies - has vacancies - no vacancies - no vacancies

Rental 2 - has vacancies - no vacancies - no vacancies

Rental 3 - no vacancies - no vacancies

Rental 4 - no vacancies

Expected Output:

Rental 1 - no vacancies

Rental 2 - has vacancies

Rental 3 - no vacancies

Rental 4 - no vacancies

Comment: Why should it add different text to each `h2`? You're using the same `obj.availability` every time through the loop.

Comment: Are you adding `h2` dynamically between calls to the function?

Comment: You must be calling the function multiple times. The first time only Rental 1 exists. The second time, Rental 1 and Rental 2 exist, and the function appends to both of them.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `forEach`. You should just append to the new `h2`, not all of them.

Comment: Yes, I am. That's what is wrong. What is the best way to go about correcting this?

Comment: When you create a new h2, set its text content before appending it.

Comment: I don't know what is the original content of `h2`  but from what i see i think this will solve your problem:
`h2.textContent = h2.textContent.split('-')[0] + " - no vacancies" `
the same goes for the else block